# students matriculation number should not be used as continous numer on x axis of geom_barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
matriculation_number int[]  grade num[]
11111                       1.2
22222                       2.0
77777                       2.8
.....                       ...
```

and use the following command:

```
boxPlot <- 
   ggplot(data = data, aes(x = matriculation_number, y = grade)) +
   geom_boxplot(aes(group=matriculation_number))) +
   xlab(matriculation_number)+
   ylab('Grades')
```

The problem is that on the x axis, where the matriculation numer should be displays, only one matriculation_number is visible. Also the x axis treats the matriculation numbers as numbers instead of a string and spreads them along the whole axis.

[image]

**How is it possible to show on each barplot the matriculation_number and how to evenly spread the matriculation_numers across the x-axis?**

Comment: Make it a factor instead of a number.

Comment: Specifically use `aes(x = factor(matriculation_number), y = grade)`

Comment: @G5W worked like a charm, if you are writing a short answer I´ll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before plotting,  make `matriculation_number` into a factor. You can either change it in the original data  with

```
data$matriculation_number = factor(data$matriculation_number)
```

or as suggested by @MrFlick you can change it in the plot statement itself with

```
boxPlot <- 
    ggplot(data = data, aes(x = factor(matriculation_number), y = grade)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(group=matriculation_number))) +
    xlab(matriculation_number)+
    ylab('Grades')
```